# System.Windows.Data Error: 4 only happend when combobox is in the listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, combobox

i getting a strange issue when i put my combobox in my listview it says it cannot find a reference for my element name win(my window name) outside of the `listview` it's working fine and do not have any problems with that.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=win'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedParam; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='Krydsmålbox'); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object')

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="Krydsmålbox" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" Background="#FF303030" FontSize="12" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTest2}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cmbTemplate2}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  SelectedValuePath="Krydsmålene"
                    SelectedValue = "{Binding SelectedParam, ElementName=win, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="138" BorderBrush="#FF303030" Height="40"/>
```

CS

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
             public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
                private string _selectedParam;
              public MainWindow()
            {
        InitializeComponent();
                    BindData();
                    ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(hjuldata.ItemsSource);
                    dataView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Mærke"));
        }
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
                    {
                        if (PropertyChanged != null)
                        {
                            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
                        }
                    }
                    public string SelectedParam { get { return _selectedParam; } set { _selectedParam = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedParam");
                    if (_selectedParam == "Krydsmål") { BindData(); } else { hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori().Tables[0].DefaultView; ; } } }

          private void BindData()
                {
                    hjuldata.ItemsSource = Kategori().Tables[0].DefaultView;
                }

        public DataSet FilterKategori()
        {

            Data = @"Select ps.Mærket AS Mærke, P.DataID, P.Billed, P.Model, P.Årgang, P.[Motor Type], P.Krydsmålet, P.Centerhul, P.ET,P.Bolter, P.Dæk, P.Fælge ,PS.Krydsmålene from Data.Hjuldata P  inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.MærkeID = PS.MærkeID WHERE Krydsmålet = @param1";

            //SQL statement to fetch entries from products
            DataSet dsdata = new DataSet();

            //Open SQL Connection
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
            {
                conn.Open();

                //Initialize command object

                using (cmd = new SqlCommand(Data, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", SelectedParam);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapters = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    //Fill the result set
                    adapters.Fill(dsdata);
                    conn.Close();

                }

            }

            return dsdata;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding by element name, I think it's better to use a RelativeSource, something like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Krydsmålbox" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" Background="#FF303030" FontSize="12" 
Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTest2}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cmbTemplate2}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}"  SelectedValuePath="Krydsmålene"
SelectedValue = "{Binding DataContext.SelectedParam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
             AncestorType= Window},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
Width="138" BorderBrush="#FF303030" Height="40"/>
```

Comment: that didn't worked 
>System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedParam; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='Krydsmålbox'); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object')

Comment: Try changing `AncestorType={x:Type Window}}` to `AncestorType= Window`

Comment: Try my last edition now. The binding must be Datacontext.Selectedparam

Comment: that didn't solved it  i had updatet my question with the code for  selected param and notify if that might help

Comment: Are you setting your View Datacontext to your Viewmodel? If you are, my last code should work

Comment: Where do you have a `this.DataContext=new ViewModel();` or similar?

Comment: i using   ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(hjuldata.ItemsSource);
                    dataView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Mærke"));

otherwise is just default views

Answer (score 0):

When you put something inside a ListView it enters an 'island of encapsulation' where it cannot reach outside of the listview and bind directly to other items in your view. You need to replacent the element binding with a `FindAncestor` binding

```
{Binding Path=SelectedParam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

Comment: now i getting this again System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedParam; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='Krydsmålbox'); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object')

Comment: ok, try binding to something further down the logical tree - replace AncestorType=Window for AncestorType=Combobox. I am assuming your Window and Combobox share the same DataContext

Comment: the same error now just with FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox